# Difference between Active MQ and Amazon MQ

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, activemq-classic, amazon-mq

I Know the theoretical difference like :

> Amazon MQ provides a managed message broker service that takes care of
>   operating ActiveMQ, including broker set up, monitoring, maintenance,
>   and provisioning the underlying infrastructure for high availability
>   and durability. You may want to consider Amazon MQ when you want to
>   offload operational overhead and associated costs.

What i am asking is there any difference in making connection, fetching data with active MQ and Amazon MQ.(On coding side mainly in java)
I think there is no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there is no difference on the code side. Both of them uses same underlying framework and libraries.

1. Only difference you might see on the code side is amazonMQ is **SSL** secured which makes it mandate to pass **username** and **password** in the code.
2. AmazonMQ works on version equal to or greater than **<5.15.8>** version for activemq related dependencies.
3. Other differences are obviously with the kind of services AWS provides like better monitoring, logs analysis, configuration management/version management of config etc.